# How to retrieve the value from the mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a beginner in nodejs and mongoose. I am trying to retrieve the category value which astname having laptop. Please suggest me how to achieve this.

```
var astname = "Laptop";

Asset.find({ astname : astname}, function(err, foundcategory){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           console.log(foundcategory.category);
       }
   })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foundcategory` is an array in your example. Use `findOne` instead of `find` to query for a single document.

```
var astname = "Laptop";

Asset.findOne({ astname : astname}, function(err, foundcategory){
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
   } else {
       console.log(foundcategory.category);
   }
})
```